# こんなものか、こんなところか at the end of sentences

Tags: meaning, phrases

I often hear these at the end of sentences or just standalone by themselves, in a questioning tone. One example：

> 纏めると、とりあえずこんな所か…

I have no problem understanding it in the larger context, but I have trouble "translating" it even as an idiomatic expression.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66245/5010

Answer (score 1):

I would expect teachers say the sentence your brought up when the lesson finishes.

Probably in a class room the teacher might close the lesson with the sentence.

> 纏めると、とりあえずこんな所か…

Let's finish up. For the time being, that's enough?

You also can say that to yourself for sure when you are wondering if you achieved the enough outcome (normal tone) or not (questioning tone) at that moment.