# what are the usages of ものか?

Tags: grammar, particles

The only definition i can find is that it expresses irony/rhetorical question, but that doesnt really fit into expressions like どういうものか? etc.

So what can be the usages of ものか?

Answer (score 1):

In どういうものか, this もの is just "thing", and no special grammar is involved here. Just as どういう本か means "What kind of book is it?", どういうものか simply translates to "What kind of thing is it?"

There are various special usages of ものか, too. Generally, you should understand ものだ ([which by itself has verious meanings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010)) first and think of ものか as its question version.

- [ものか in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96484/5010)
- [Alternative meaning of ものか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66245/5010)
- [What is the meaning of this ものか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97293/5010)
- [how does te form+ なる(ものか) work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96058/5010)

Comment: Hm, i have read the others posts, and i wanna ask, how does the meaning change if i change the いくほどの年を経た**ものか** to いくほどの年を経た**のか**?

Comment: @prdelsmradkava It's ものだ for "recollection and reminiscence" explained in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43127/5010), but in its question form. "*(Ah, I wonder)* how many years have passed?" Basically the ものか version sounds more exclamatory and emotional.